# Apply static IP address change in /etc/network/interfaces in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, ip, ifconfig, static-ip

**TL;DR:** In Ubuntu 14.04, If you change a static IP address in `/etc/network/interfaces` and apply the changes with `ifdown` and then `ifup` command everything works fine. But this sequence is not working in 16.04. What is the best alternative?

In ubuntu 16.04, after changing interfaces file and `ifdown/ifup` sequence, `ip addr show <device>` command shows both old and new static IP addresses for `<device>`. I used `-v` (verbose) argument with `ifdown/ifup` in both ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04. The difference was in ifdown. In ubuntu 14.04 `ifdown` executes this command:

```
ip -4 addr flush dev <device> label <device>
```

While in 16.04:

```
ip addr del <ip-address-in-network-interfaces>/<subnet> dev <device> label <device>
```

So I figured out, in 16.04, If I first run the `ifdown` command. Then change the IP address in `/etc/network/interfaces` file and then use the ifup command to bring the interface up again, the old IP address will be deleted correctly.

Another solution is running the `ip addr flush` command before `ifdown/ifup`:

```
ip addr flush dev <device>
```

It seems that I already answered my question, but I want to know what are the alternatives and what is the best solution to change a static IP address in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: The question is if this issue is a bug or it is a planned change?
Will we see this behavior in the next releases of Ubuntu?

Comment: it's becuase ubuntu uses network manager for all network connections and that doesn't work anymore (at least in desktop) so if you go to your graphical ethernet/wifi config and change it from dhcp to static in the options, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can add flush inside interfaces definition like

> iface eth0 inet manual
>   post-down ip addr flush dev $IFACE