# changes to /etc/network/interfaces ignored (16.04 server)

Tags: networking, 16.04, server

i tried to change the static ip address of one of my servers on the command line - and failed!

the original `/etc/network/interfaces` looks something like this

```
auto enp2s0f0
iface enp2s0f0 inet static
        address     192.168.0.57
        netmask     255.255.255.0
        gateway     192.168.0.1

auto enp2s0f1
iface enp2s0f1 inet static
        address     192.168.1.57
        netmask     255.255.255.0
```

and the configuration is ok when i boot the system. now i tried to change the subnet of the second interface to `192.168.10`. i edited  `/etc/network/interfaces` and tried to get the interface to accept this new configuration.

but no combination of

```
$ sudo systemctl restart networking.service
$ sudo ifdown enp2s0f1 && sudo ifup enp2s0f1
$ sudo ifconfig enp2s0f1 down && sudo ifconfig enp2s0f1 up
```

changes the ip address of that interface.

i am not sure if this is related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1301015) or if i'm misunderstanding the new `systemctl`-way of restarting services.

on ubuntu 12.04 this just worked fine.

just rebooting the machine works fine. but it must be possible to reload and apply the information in `/etc/network/interfaces` (i even tried `ifup` with the flag `-i /etc/network/interfaces` - to no avail).

---

**UPDATE:**

as stated in [this unanswered question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793877/apply-static-ip-address-change-in-etc-network-interfaces-in-ubuntu-16-04): this works (but seems *very* clumsy):

```
$ sudo ifdown enp2s0f1
$ sudo ip addr flush dev enp2s0f1
$ sudo ifup enp2s0f1
```

is there really no simpler way in ubuntu 16.04?